# Factor Infinite Sum into Infinite Product

Tags: sequences-and-series

If you have the $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^i}$, obviously it equals $n/(n-1)$.  However, is there an infinite factorization of that sum?

Comment: Well, notice that the series is not obviously converge yet, e.g. let $n= 1$

Comment: You can make an infinite factorization of any finite number. In fact you can make an infinite number of infinite factorizations. What in particular is your interest and intention with this question?